# Немного о CSRF дырах, Jquery + MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

Узнал, что такое CSRF дыры, сразу побежал их латать. С отправкой форм всё сразу хорошо сложилось, но с запросами использующие ajax не очень. Дело в том, что меня даже не пускает в действие контроллера.
В проекте MVC, в представлении, вызывается `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` для генерации токена и действие контроллера помечается атрибутом `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. При отправке формы, токен улетал вместе с формой, но для этого требовалось перезагрузить страницу. Для мелких действий вроде отправки уведомления перезагрузка страницы уж слишком накладно и неудобно.
В асинхронном запросе я просто добавлял токен в строку URL и отправлял на сервер, но по прежнему не пускает в действие контроллера.

```
function send() {
    var login = $("#login").val();
    var token = $("#content").find("input").filter(':hidden').attr("name") + "=" + $("#content").find("input").filter(':hidden').val() //Здесь обращаемся к input содержащим токен
    $.ajax({
        method: "Get",
        url: "@Url.Action("SendAnnounced", "Announced")?From=@Model.Id&To=" + login + "&Type=0&" + token,
    });
}
```

Действие контроллера:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void SendAnnounced(AnnouncedModel model)
{
    if (Auth.IsAuthentication)
        Auth.SendAnnounced(model);
}
```

Есть ли решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Почему-то для отправки запроса используется GET метод. Что-то мне подсказывает, что надо использовать POST
2. В тело запроса вместе с данными надо положить сам antiforgery token

   ```
       var data = { 'login': $('#login').val(), '__RequestVerificationToken': $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() };
       $.post('@Url.Action("SendAnnounced", "Announced")', data);
   ```

Ну и подробнее про использование antiforgery token с ajax и webapi можно почитать тут http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks